# Question about random variables convergence: Relationship between the different notions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let a random variable $Y>0$ (a.s.) and a sequence $X_n\rightarrow0$ in probability. I want to prove that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-n(X_n+Y)}\right]=0$$.

Is it true? Or do I need some extra hypothesis?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true. Let $Y = 1$ and $(X_n)$ be an independent sequence with $X_n = 0$ with probability $1 - 1/n$ and $X_n = -n$ with probability $1/n$. Note that $(X_n)$ converges to $0$ in probability.

Then $\mathbb E[\exp(-n(X_n + Y))] = (1-1/n) \exp(-n) + 1/n \exp(n^2-n)$, which does not converge to zero.

Note that convergence in probability does not imply convergence in mean. You need also uniform integrability.