# A specific problem about random variables convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My question is related with [this other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4098181/question-about-random-variables-convergence-relationship-between-the-different).

Let the random variable $Y$ and the set $E=\left\{\omega\in\Omega:\;Y(\omega)\leq0\right\}$, where $\Omega$ is the sample space. Let a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ such that $X_n\rightarrow0$ with probability one (maybe slowly and from negatives). I want to prove that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-n(X_n+Y)}\mathbf{1}\{E^c\}\right]=0$$
I think that it is true because I can use Fatou reverse lemma:
$$\lim\sup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-n(X_n+Y)}\mathbf{1}\{E^c\}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\displaystyle-\lim\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty} n(X_n+Y)}\mathbf{1}\{E^c\}\right]$$
and for all $\omega\in E^c$ $Y>0$. But I have doubts with tho things:

- I cannot ensure that there exists $\eta>0$ such that $Y>\eta$.
- I cannot ensure that $X_n=\mathcal{o}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Is my reasoning correct? How can I formalize the demonstration? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the assertion is wrong. Let $Y$ uniform on $(0,1)$ and $X_n=1/\sqrt{n}$. (so $X_n$ is a const. random variable)
$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-n(X_n+Y)}\mathbf{1}\{E^c\}\right]= \mathbb{E}\left[e^{-n(-n^{-1/2}+Y)}\right] = e^{\sqrt{n} } \mathbb{E}\left[ e^{-nY} \right] = e^{\sqrt{n}}\int_0^1 e^{-int}dt = e^{\sqrt{n}} \frac{1 - e^{-n}}{n} $$

For suitable large $n$ the latter is bigger than $ \frac{e^{\sqrt{n}}}{2n}$, which goes to $\infty$ for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: yes, sure. sry for the typo.

Comment: Yes, your answer is perfect. Do you know what happens if $n\cdot X_n\rightarrow0$ with probability one?

Comment: You have a second problem here: It is very unclear, if $\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-n(X_n+Y)}\mathbf{1}\{E^c\}\right]$ exists for even for fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Example $X$ s.t. $\mathbb{P}[X=-1/k]=6/(\pi^2 k^2)$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$. (If you want to fit it into your problem excatly, set $X_n := X/n^2$ s.t. $n X_n \to 0$ a.s. and $Y=1$.) Then the expectation fails to exist. (You could fix that by assuming your RV to be bounded)